# iPhone app 3d engine or not

Tags: iphone, 3d, opengl-es, core-graphics

I am developing a simple iPhone app, which:

- retrieves data from the server
- presents the data

In order to present the data better I want to add **nice 3d dynamic objects**, for example:

- a car with spinning wheels next to car sales bar chart.
- power plant with smoke coming out of the chimney next to CO2 emission numbers

The questions are:

- How do I work with the designer on this, what output should he provide for me (format)?
- How do I put it in my application, should I involve some 3d engine/framework?

Answer (score 1):

The team behind cocos2D has just announced cocos**3D** and this seems really promising. 
The first public beta can be downloaded

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1274

Answer (score 0):

You can use cocos2d for the iPhone and fake 3d with the art.  So, you have a car that is drawn to look 3d but you're only using 2d to display it.  The effects that you want to do don't require to use full 3d models.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have a look at this one I discovered recently:

http://nineveh.gl/

It's pretty new but well documented and with video demos.